# Is there a way to change the windows 7 theme using python or batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, themes, desktop, composition

I try to change the windows 7 theme temporarily using python or a batch script without the need of administrator rights.

Currently I have a way where I have to interact with windows using the following:

```
@echo off
if not "%1"=="am_admin" (powershell start -verb runas '%0' am_admin & exit /b)
net stop uxsms >nul
```

I think it's enough if I can access the compatibility option "Disable desktop composition"

Comment: You would need to run a few rundll32 commands.. to get the Cpl files to update theme files.

Comment: Did a quick search, [here](https://msfn.org/board/topic/154625-help-batch-file-changing-windows-7-theme/) is something similar.